# How to prevent child-process to kill the main node process running in nobody user permission

Tags: node.js, linux, child-process

I have an index.js file which forks a temp.js file. The index.js file runs in nobody (non-root) user permission level. Hence, it is not possible to kill any other processes.
But, from the forked process (i.e. temp.js) I can grep the pid of the parent process and kill it.

Is it possible to prevent the child process to run a bash command to kill the parent process?

This is my **index.js**

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./temp');

child.on('message', function(m) {
  console.log('received: ' + m);
});

// Send child process some work
child.send('kill me');
```

This is my **temp.js**

```
let exec = require('child_process');

process.on('message', function (m) {
    console.log("Message from parent: " + m);
    exec("kill $(ps ax | grep mytestproc | awk '{print $1}')", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            return;
        }
        console.log('exec stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('exec stderr: ' + stderr);
    });
});
```

Comment: Except for the kernel module that disables the syscall, the user can always write his/her own kill executable by calling the function `kill`. So I think the way out for your problem is to disable the kill function for the user.

Comment: BUT I really recommend you do not do this, since kill isn't just use to kill a process, but it is used to send signals and that is a fundamental function of the OS, so you don't want to disable it. Just accept that processes created by users can be finalized by them.

Comment: Your assumption seems to be wrong. Non-root processes are allowed to kill other processes that run under the same UID. It has nothing to do with parent-child relationship. The way to prevent it is to run processes under different users.

Comment: @ErkiA yes I agree to your point that "Non-root processes are allowed to kill other processes that run under the same UID". Point is considering mine is the only process running in that particular UID how to prevent the child to kill the parent.

Comment: @Roy The only reliable way is to run these processes under different UID-s. So you need your process to be able to do setuid() or let some other process that has setuid() capability to create the new process for you. But the latter needs a redesign of your application.